# Java enum.valueOf(String) and enum.class

Tags: java, class, object, types, enums

I have few enums like the following:

```
public enum Season {
    SPRING, SUMMER, AUTUM, WINTER
}

public enum Day {
    SUNDAY, MONDAY, TUESDAY, WEDNESDAY, 
    THURSDAY, FRIDAY, SATURDAY 
}
```

I am trying to write a common method for a concern.

```
private void doSomethingWithAnyEnum(Class enumClass,String checkThisProperty) 
{
  if(EnumUtils.isValidEnum(enumClass, checkThisProperty))
  {
    //here i should be able to call valueOf(String) method on enum
    //without bothering about the type coming in. 
  }
}
```

So that I can call this method like:

```
doSomethingWithAnyEnum(Days.class,"blah") ;
doSomethingWithAnyEnum(Seasons.class,"blah");
```

I am stuck on how to pass a enum and use it's class and name in the method using the same thing. I tried using `simpleName()` but it doesn't do the job here. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: _"...and use it's class and name in the method using the same thing"_ What do you mean by this? Can you give an example of what you're trying to do?

Comment: I am clueless what you might mean with "do something with [...] but in a more generic way."

Comment: @f1sh Edited the commented portion for clarity. Please let me know if it's clear.

Answer (score 2):

You may want to modify your function like this:

```
public <T extends Enum<T>> void doSomethingWithAnyEnum(Class<T> tClass, String name) {
    T t  = Enum.valueOf(tClass, name);
}
```

Your original method took a random `Class enumClass` class type, which accept any class. It will throw runtime exceptions when treat input class as enum

Answer (score 2):

`EnumUtils` from Apache Commons already has a method to do this: [`getEnum`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.1/org/apache/commons/lang3/EnumUtils.html#getEnum(java.lang.Class,%20java.lang.String)). As you're already using it for `isValidEnum`, it makes sense to use it for this as well.

Your method signature should also use generics rather than raw types to enforce at compile-time that `doSomethingWithAnyEnum` is called with an enum and not any old class. I have fixed that for you as well.

```
private <E extends Enum<E>> void doSomethingWithAnyEnum(Class<E> enumClass,
                                                        String checkThisProperty)
{
    if (EnumUtils.isValidEnum(enumClass, checkThisProperty))
    {
        final E value = EnumUtils.getEnum(enumClass, checkThisProperty);
        System.out.println(value.name()); //or whatever else you want to do
    }
}
```

Without this change to the method signature, I could call this method with

```
doSomethingWithAnyEnum(String.class, "hello")
```

and it would only fail at runtime. It's better to do the check at compile-time.